# Handle ConcurrentModificationException for simultaneous access

Tags: java, android, android-service

in my application i have a simple `Service` to get some data from web service and in main activity i'm viewing saved data.For this action i'm using this class structure to set structure of data for saving it into database and read data with this structure to view items into Android `ListView`, using this class structure maybe simultaneous access and i get error

ReceivedItemStructure class structure:

```
public class ReceivedItemStructure implements Serializable {
    public String  mLastID;
    public String  mUserID;
    public String  mSmsBody;
    public String  mMobileNumber;
    public String  mDate;
    public String  mSenderName;
    public String  mSmsNumber;
    public String  mContactName;
    public Integer mRead; 
    public Bitmap  mPhoto;
}
```

`saveReceivedItemsToDatabase` method for save data into database :

```
public void saveReceivedItemsToDatabase(List<ReceivedItemStructure> receiveRow, String username) {
    if (receiveRow != null) {
        for (ReceivedItemStructure rf : receiveRow) {
        /* Find Duplicate row if not exist then can be write into DataBase */
            if (!G.db.searchLastID ( username, rf.getmLastID () )) {
                addReceivedToDataBase ( new ReceivedItemStructure (
                        rf.getmLastID (),
                        username,
                        rf.getmSmsBody (),
                        rf.getmSmsNumber (),
                        rf.getmSenderName (),
                        rf.getmContactName (),
                        rf.getmDate (),
                        rf.getmRead (),
                        rf.getmPhoto ()
                ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and now in this method i read from database with that class structure (thats cause of error when start activity) simultaneous access (save data into database from service and read from database and fill `ReceivedItemStructure` class with some data:

```
public static void fillItems(ContentResolver cr){
    Cursor cursor = db.getReceivedCursorFromDatabase(config_username);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String name = "";
    String id   = "";
    items.clear ();
    if ( cursor != null && cursor.getCount() != 0 ) {
        do {
            ...
            items.add(item);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

`items` is :

```
public static ArrayList<ReceivedItemStructure> items;
```

in `G` class extends from `Application`. now how to handle this error and modirate that?

POST UPDATE:

```
public void addReceivedToDataBase(ReceivedItemStructure fields) {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_LASTID,       fields.getmLastID());           // ReceiveFields last ID
    values.put(COLUMN_USERID,       fields.getmUserID());           // ReceiveFields last ID
    values.put(COLUMN_MOBILENUMBER, fields.getmMobileNumber());
    values.put(COLUMN_SENDERNAME,   fields.getmSenderName()); 
    values.put(COLUMN_SMSBODY,      fields.getmSmsBody());
    values.put(COLUMN_SMSNUMBER,    fields.getmSmsNumber());
    values.put(COLUMN_RECEIVEDATE,  fields.getmDate());
    values.put(COLUMN_READ_STATE ,  fields.getmRead ());
    db.insert(RECEIVE_FIELDS_TABLE, null, values);
}
```

Read web service in Service and save data to database:

```
public static void getRequestFromServer (long lastID, int count, ContentResolver cr) throws JSONException {
    String received = null;
    String firstID = "";
    try {
        received = new JsonService ( config_username, config_password, lastID, count, F_RECEIVE_SMS ).request ();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
        return;
    }
        /* UPDATE CODE */ 
        items_temp = new ArrayList<ReceivedItemStructure> ();

        JSONArray object = new JSONArray ( received );
        JSONArray data_array = null;
        data_array = new JSONArray ( received );

        String mUserID = config_username;
        JSONObject json_obj = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < data_array.length (); i++) {
            try {
                json_obj = data_array.getJSONObject ( i );
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ();
                DebugLog.log ( String.valueOf ( e ) );
            }
            String mLastID     = null;
            String mSmsBody    = null;
            String mSmsNumber  = null;
            String mSenderName = null;
            mLastID     = json_obj.getString  ( "id_recived_sms" );
            mSmsBody    = json_obj.getString  ( "sms_body" );
            mSmsNumber  = json_obj.getString  ( "sms_number" );
            mSenderName = json_obj.getString  ( "mobile_number" );
            String mContactName = getContentNameFromContactList ( mSenderName , cr);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty ( mContactName ))
            /* if contact name not exist in contact show resolve by service */
                mContactName = mSenderName;

            String mDate = null;
                  mDate = json_obj.getString ( "recived_date" );
            Bitmap mPhoto = getContactPhoto ( mSenderName , cr );
            ReceivedItemStructure item = new ReceivedItemStructure ();
            item.setmLastID       ( mLastID );
            item.setmUserID       ( mUserID );
            item.setmSmsBody      ( mSmsBody );
            item.setmSmsNumber    ( mSmsNumber );
            item.setmSenderName   ( mSenderName );
            item.setmContactName  ( mContactName );
            item.setmDate         ( mDate );
            /* set read to false, after clicking on viewGroup thats set to true */
            item.setmRead         ( 0 ); /* that means FALSE  */
            item.setmPhoto        ( mPhoto );

            /* UPDATE CODE */ 
            items_temp.add ( item );

        }
        /* UPDATE CODE */ 
        db.saveReceivedItemsToDatabase ( items_temp, config_username );
}
```

and if user run application i read from database and fill ReceivedItemStructure  class with `fillItems` method ( simultaneous access ).

**UPDATE POST 2:**

after define new ArrayList as `items_temp` and seperate `G.items` from service with items_temp () and activity. sometimes i have problem and my application crash.

`items_temp` in `G` class is:

```
public static ArrayList<ReceivedItemStructure> items_temp;
```

LogCat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:569)
    at ir.tsms.DataBase.DatabaseHandler.saveReceivedItemsToDatabase(DatabaseHandler.java:133)
    at ir.tsms.Class.G.getRequestFromServer(G.java:339)
    at ir.tsms.ServiceDialog$LongOperation.doInBackground(ServiceDialog.java:179)
    at ir.tsms.ServiceDialog$LongOperation.doInBackground(ServiceDialog.java:173)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    ... 4 more
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:569)
    at ir.tsms.DataBase.DatabaseHandler.saveReceivedItemsToDatabase(DatabaseHandler.java:133)
    at ir.tsms.Class.G.getRequestFromServer(G.java:339)
    at ir.tsms.ServiceDialog$LongOperation.doInBackground(ServiceDialog.java:179)
    at ir.tsms.ServiceDialog$LongOperation.doInBackground(ServiceDialog.java:173)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `addReceivedToDataBase` adds an element to the `receiveRow` List, that's the cause of the exception you got. You can't alter a List (add/remove elements) while iterating over it with the enhanced for loop.

EDIT:

You shouldn't use the `public static ArrayList<ReceivedItemStructure> items` list for both storing data received from the server and storing data loaded from the DB, since as you noticed, these two processes can interfere with each other.

When you load data from the server, store it in a different `List`, and save to the database. Once you are done updating the database, re-load the data from the database into `items` (by calling `fillItems`).

Comment: yes. i know it. how to handle this exception? for example lock and release that to use

Comment: @andbee Can you show the code of `addReceivedToDataBase`?

Comment: @andbee I still don't see where you are inserting or removing elements from `receiveRow` List. Is there such a place?

Comment: Hi sir. my problem after sometimes dont resolved. i'm update post with new LogCat.please help me. thanks

Comment: @andbee Well, `saveReceivedItemsToDatabase` now accepts `items_temp`. It's initialized in `getRequestFromServer`. Isn't that the only method that modifies `items_temp`? If that's the case, the only reason I can see for this exception is if you are running `getRequestFromServer` on multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: you means is define `public static ArrayList<ReceivedItemStructure> items_temp;` into `getRequestFromServer ` as `ArrayList<ReceivedItemStructure>  items_temp = new ArrayList<ReceivedItemStructure> ();` ??

Answer (score 0):

Use iterator instead of enhanced for loop.

For an example:
    `for (Iterator iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        E element = iter.next();
        ...
    }`

Comment: please complete your code. how to get elements from class structure with this code?

Comment: Just cast with your class which is in list. (i.e.  ReceivedItemStructure element = (ReceivedItemStructure) iter.next();)
Hope this will help you!